# Как правильно задать "конкурсный творческий" вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

Допустим, есть интересный вопрос, который имеет целью, скорее, развлечение от программирования, нежели "проблему в программировании", например, как [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674415/). Некий "фан", если хотите. Как правильно задать такой вопрос, чтобы "особо добрые люди" (пальцем показывать не будем) его не закидали тапками?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=code+golf